# Live Webcam on ASP.NET Web Site

Tags: asp.net, webcam

I need a way to put a live web cam video on my ASP.NET application.

I basically want answers from people who have done this before.  What is the easiest and most cost-effective way to accomplish a simple web cam feed?  Technically, it does not have to be streaming video (although that is the preference).

I could settle for an image that refreshes every few seconds.

Comment: You have filtered your answers quite well, but not asked a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could use an [Axis](http://www.axis.com/products/video/camera/index.htm) Web Camera which has an embedded webserver. This would probably cost a bit more than a cheap PC web cam but supports web streaming directly.  Unfortunately, this would not scale well as the embedded webserver can only handle a few concurrent connections.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I will look into it.  The scalability is not a major issue - I will not have a huge audience and am more than willing to limit the number of connections.  Thanks again!

Comment: Excellent.  I got a different IP camera but it was pretty much the same idea (with built in web server).  To embed on web page, I did not have good options for video though.  So on server, I setup 500ms timer to download new image and cache it.  Then I wrote jQuery code to make ajax request to update IMG tag ind the DOM.  Works great.  Not exactly live, but it works good enough for me, and degrades gracefully for slower Internet connections.  THANK YOU!

Comment: I should've mentioned that this particular camera had an embedded SNAPSHOT perl script that was able to stream the image to me.  All I had to do was do programmatic Basic Authentication to request it and then cache it on server.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it went well.  If possible, send us a link if/when the site goes public :)  PS.  Do you consider the question answered now?